# What is the difference between JHipster modules (entity, entity-client, entity-server, entity-i18n and entities)

Tags: jhipster

I'm trying to create a blueprint from JHipster by customizing the sub-module entity. After I navigate to the source code, I can see in total there are several packages (folder) related to the entity module. As well as mention at this link https://www.jhipster.tech/modules/creating-a-blueprint/

If anybody knows about it, please feel free to share your opinions, I have performed some research but the result was poor. Thanks in advance

Comment: These are different parts of the entity "module". E.g. entity-client is about the client code (e.g. vue or angular) while entity-server contains the server side api implementation. These are dedicated modules/generators which are eventually composed to create everything required for the complete entity module. Think of a blueprint for e.g. quarkus or micronaut. They don't need to change the client part but just the server part.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm really appreciated your help. Have a great day.

Comment: @atomfrede I wonder if you know the difference between entity and entities?

Comment: entity is the generator to create/generate one entity, while entities is used to regenerate all entities from the current configuration if I am not mistaken. Entities basically is the generator doing the composition of all smaller subgens.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer helped me a lot. Have a great day, btw may I have your Linkedin?

Comment: You should find all on my personal blog